# HTML table with alternating row colors via XSL

Tags: html, xslt, html-table

What is the easiest way to alternate row colors in an HTML table (a.ka. striping). Most of my tables are created in XSL templates like the following, with the table, thead, etc.. defined in another template.

```
<xsl:template match="typ:info">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="typ:dateAccessed" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="typ:loginId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

My preference is to use alternating classes on the  elements.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you must produce hard-coded colors in HTML:

```
<xsl:template match="typ:info">
  <xsl:variable name="css-class">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">even</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>odd</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <tr class="{$css-class}">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="typ:dateAccessed" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="typ:loginId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

With today's browsers you are much better off using CSS and `tr:nth-child(odd)`.

This results in less hassle on the XSLT side, much cleaner HTML markup - and it's compatible with client-side table sorting and -filtering.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use css3.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #ff0000; }
```

Supported as of IE9 an for quite some time by all the other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XSL:When and compare position mod 2 to get odd or even rows to alter classes when needed like:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <td class="odds">blah</td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <td class="even">blah</td>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**EDIT:** Getting my odd/even the right way around *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

May we want to change only the class name instead, when can choose inside a variable to enable change its inner value. Something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="myDemoClass" >
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
       <xsl:text>myDemoClass</xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:text>myDemoClass otherClass</xsl:text>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

With this, we are able to change the variable name and then we can change for example, a div class content.

```
<div class="{$myDemoClass}">
```

Regards!

Comment: I was, in my code, trying to modify a xsl variable value and I made something like this. At the end I figured I could also be used to solve this kind "even-odd" iteration. I know this is solved men, but this is a slightly different approach of cooking the same thing. Lets say I want to collaborate more, don't you?