# Alternating row colours in a tr class using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XSL document which has a varaible number of articles inserted into it. I need the background colours of the articles to alternate - "Odd" then "even"

```
<xsl:for-each select="newsletter/section/article">
    <tr class="odd" style="background-color: #efefef;">
        <td valign="top">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="link" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <img align="left" valign="top" width="110" 
                            style="padding: 0 4px 4px 0; border:0;">
                    <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="img" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </xsl:element>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 4px 4px 18px 0;">
            <strong>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="link" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </strong>
            <br />
            <xsl:value-of select="excerpt"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Ive looked at this post: [HTML table with alternating row colors via XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469917/html-table-with-alternating-row-colors-via-xsl)

but my case is different I believe. I just need to change the tr class on each iteration. Sorry for the weird formatting, I seem to be having problems pasting code in Chrome on here.

Comment: Could you explain more about how your requirements are different to those in the post you've linked to.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution. :)

Comment: In fact it's a exact duplicate of [HTML table with alternating row colors via XSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469917/html-table-with-alternating-row-colors-via-xsl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="newsletter/section/article">
  <xsl:variable name="vColor">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <xsl:text>#efefef</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>#ababab</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>


  <tr class="odd" style="background-color: {$vColor};">
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved it. Reading through the question I linked (after I understand it) I see that my requirements were similar ,so thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @dimitre - Is the ` = 1` necessary? I get the expected results if I just do: `        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() mod 2">
            <xsl:text>#efefef</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>#ababab</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>`. Is there a reason this would be a bad idea?

Comment: @DevNull. I guess it's OK. Just a number->boolean conversion.

Comment: @DevNull: It's not really needed for this case, but when you start working with triplets you notice that rest of division become 1, 2, 0. So, in any tuple, 1 is the rest for the first position and 0 belongs to the last.

Comment: @DevNull: To add to the correct answers by @Alejandro and @Flack: Yes, they are equivalent in this case, but the more explicit is more easy to understand. If you have to thinl "what this means" you are wasting more time (at best) and you risk misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:for-each select="date">
    <tr>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">odd</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color: #efefef;"
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <td valign="top">
            <a href="{link}">
                <img align="left" valign="top" width="110"
                            style="padding: 0 4px 4px 0; border:0;"
                            alt="{title}"
                            src="{img}"/>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 4px 4px 18px 0;">
            <strong>
                <a href="{link}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </a>
            </strong>
            <br />
            <xsl:value-of select="excerpt"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: +1 for also showing the OP how to clean up the code with AVT's.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position()` and the remainder when dividing by two.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is very similar. The thing you should do is to define a class name based on position. @Jim Garrison gives you good prompt but I think that example is necessary because there are examples with `position()` in the examples you reference and the question is asked.

```
<xsl:for-each select="newsletter/section/article">
  <!-- create index-based variable -->
  <xsl:variable name="classname">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
        <xsl:text>even</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:text>odd</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <!-- insert contents of your variable -->
  <tr class="{$classname}" style="background-color: #efefef;">
....
```