# Alternate table row color via XSL in generating pdf

Tags: xslt

I am very new to XSLT. I want to implement alternate colors in my table rows.The Even rows should be displayed - #EDF2F8 and Odd rows - #A7BFDE.

I have a xsl which looks like :

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="records"/>

<xsl:template match="records">
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="Firstname"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="Phone number"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
```

I tried using the below code but it did not work:

```
<xsl:variable name="css-class">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
<xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#EDF2F8</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#A7BFDE</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<fo:table-row class="{$css-class}">
   <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="Firstname"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="Phone number"/>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
```

I really appreciate any help on this.

Part of my code which  I edited to and it did not work either :

```
<xsl:template match="records">
<xsl:variable name="bgclr">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#A7BFDE</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>#EDF2F8</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<fo:table-row bgcolor="{$bgclr}">
<fo:table-cell padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="1.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="0.5pt">
<fo:block xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" space-after="10pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.4911" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" text-align="left" font-weight="bold" linefeed-treatment="preserve">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

.....<-- Similar more table cells -->

Edit 3
The input data is in JSON format like :

```
"pdfrequest" : {
        "records" : [{
                "firstname" : "--",
                "lastname" : "--",
                "phoneno" : "--",
                }]
}
```

Edit 4.
Below is the sample XSL which I am using. This transforms the JSON to pdf. Any help is appreciated.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.1" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="pdfrequest">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
<fo:layout-master-set xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="section1-first-page" page-width="12in" page-height="8.5in" margin-top="36pt" margin-bottom="36pt" margin-right="10pt" margin-left="10pt">
<fo:region-body margin-top="10pt" margin-bottom="70pt"/>
<fo:region-before region-name="first-page-header" extent="11in"/>
<fo:region-after region-name="first-page-footer" extent="11in" display-align="after"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="section1-odd-page" page-width="12in" page-height="8.5in" margin-top="36pt" margin-bottom="36pt" margin-right="10pt" margin-left="10pt">
<fo:region-body margin-top="49pt" margin-bottom="61pt"/>
<fo:region-before region-name="odd-page-header" extent="11in"/>
<fo:region-after region-name="odd-page-footer" extent="11in" display-align="after"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="section1-even-page" page-width="12in" page-height="8.5in" margin-top="36pt" margin-bottom="36pt" margin-right="10pt" margin-left="10pt">
<fo:region-body margin-top="49pt" margin-bottom="61pt"/>
<fo:region-before region-name="even-page-header" extent="11in"/>
<fo:region-after region-name="even-page-footer" extent="11in" display-align="after"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="section1-page-sequence-master">
<fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="section1-first-page"/>
<fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
<fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="odd" master-reference="section1-odd-page"/>
<fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="even" master-reference="section1-even-page"/>
</fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" master-reference="section1-page-sequence-master" format="1">
</fo:static-content>
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-footnote-separator">
<fo:block>
<fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="144pt" rule-thickness="0.5pt" rule-style="solid" color="gray"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<fo:block widows="2" orphans="2" font-size="10pt" line-height="1.147" white-space-collapse="false">
<fo:marker xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" marker-class-name="first-page-header">
<fo:block space-after="0pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-size="11pt" language="EN-US" start-indent="-40.5pt">
<fo:leader/>
</fo:block>
</fo:marker>
<fo:marker xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" marker-class-name="first-page-footer">
<fo:block space-after="0pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-size="11pt" language="EN-US">
<fo:leader/>
</fo:block>
</fo:marker>
<fo:marker xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" marker-class-name="even-page-header"/>
<fo:marker xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" marker-class-name="even-page-footer"/>
<fo:block space-after="10pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.3190500000000002" font-size="16pt" language="EN-US" start-indent="0pt" space-before="18pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" font-weight="bold" color="#0070C0">
<fo:inline font-weight="bold" color="#0070C0" font-size="16pt">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
Summary Report
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
<fo:table xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" language="EN-US" start-indent="0pt" border-top-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="1pt" border-left-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="1pt" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-right-style="solid" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-width="1pt" table-layout="fixed" table-omit-header-at-break="false">
<fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="76.7pt"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="76.7pt"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="76.7pt"/>
<fo:table-header start-indent="0pt" end-indent="0pt">
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9" padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="1.5pt" background-color="#4F81BD">
<fo:block space-after="0pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" space-before="6pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" text-align="left" font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF">
<fo:inline font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF" font-size="9pt">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
Section 1
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2" padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="1.5pt" background-color="#4F81BD">
<fo:block space-after="0pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" space-before="6pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" text-align="left" font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF">
<fo:inline font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF" font-size="9pt">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
Section 2
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="1.5pt" background-color="#4F81BD">
<fo:block space-after="0pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" space-before="6pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" text-align="left" font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF">
<fo:inline font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF" font-size="9pt">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
Name
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="1.5pt" background-color="#4F81BD">
<fo:block space-after="0pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" space-before="6pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" text-align="left" font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF">
<fo:inline font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF" font-size="9pt">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
Phone no
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="1.5pt" background-color="#4F81BD">
<fo:block space-after="0pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" space-before="6pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" text-align="left" font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF">
<fo:inline font-weight="bold" color="#FFFFFF" font-size="9pt">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
Email
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-header>
<fo:table-body>
<xsl:template match="/pdfrequest">
<fo:root>
<xsl:apply-templates select="records"/>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</fo:block>
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="records">
<xsl:variable name="bgclr">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#A7BFDE</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>#EDF2F8</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<fo:table-row bgcolor="{$bgclr}">
<fo:table-cell padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="1.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="0.5pt">
<fo:block xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" space-after="10pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.4911" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" text-align="left" font-weight="bold" linefeed-treatment="preserve">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
<xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="0pt" padding-left="0.1pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="0.5pt">
<fo:block xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" space-after="10pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.4911" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" text-align="center" font-weight="bold" linefeed-treatment="preserve">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
<xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-left-color="#FFFFFF" border-right-color="#FFFFFF" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="#FFFFFF" border-bottom-color="#FFFFFF" border-top-width="0.5pt" border-bottom-width="0.5pt">
<fo:block xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" space-after="10pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.4911" font-size="9pt" language="EN-US" text-align="left" font-weight="bold" linefeed-treatment="preserve">
<fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
<xsl:value-of select="phoneno"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be? Do you want the table-row to have a class attribute or a bgcolor attribute?

Comment: I tried with both but was unable to fix the issue. I am fine with anyone among class attribute or a bgcolor attribute. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959454/alternating-row-colours-in-a-tr-class-using-xsl)

Comment: Instead of saying "did not work", post an input example and the expected output after transforming it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Complete input xsl is mentioned.

Comment: The input is JSON as mentioned.Thank you

Comment: "*The input is JSON as mentioned.*" As mentioned where? You didn't mention JSON until now. If you had, I would have told you that XSLT processes XML, not JSON. You say that your XSLT "transforms into a pdf with 11 columns and multiple rows" - and I say that's not possible with the input you show us.

Comment: Actually, adding the JSON input only adds confusion. It should not be related to the question -- only the XML input is. Because now we have another question: what **XML** are you inputting? (And if the answer is "I don't know", then what tool or command are you using to feed the JSON into your XSLT?)

Comment: If your tool suggests that this is supposed to work then presumably there's a component in there that transforms the JSON to some sort of XML API (e.g. [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org)), so a good start would be to run it with a pure identity transformation and post the result of that - that would show us the XML format that your stylesheet is really working with.

Comment: The sample xsl used in my code is mentioned in Edit 4. Apologies for the late reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:variable name="bgclr">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() mod 2">#A7BFDE</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>#EDF2F8</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<fo:table-row bgcolor="{$bgclr}">
    ...
```

Or:

```
<xsl:variable name="cls">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() mod 2">odd</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>even</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<fo:table-row class="{$cls}">
    ...
```

---

### Edit:

Since you didn't post a complete example of input, stylesheet and expected output, I am posting (a minimal) one here. Given the following example input:

```
<input>  
    <record>
        <firstname>Adam</firstname> 
        <lastname>Adams</lastname>
        <phonenumber>555-111</phonenumber>
    </record>
    <record>
        <firstname>Betty</firstname> 
        <lastname>Blue</lastname>
        <phonenumber>555-222</phonenumber>
    </record>
    <record>
        <firstname>Cecil</firstname> 
        <lastname>Crawford</lastname>
        <phonenumber>555-333</phonenumber>
    </record>
 </input>
```

the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <fo:root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="record"/>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:variable name="bgclr">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() mod 2">#A7BFDE</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>#EDF2F8</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <fo:table-row bgcolor="{$bgclr}">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="phonenumber"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:table-row bgcolor="#A7BFDE">
    <fo:table-cell>Adam</fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>Adams</fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>555-111</fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-row bgcolor="#EDF2F8">
    <fo:table-cell>Betty</fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>Blue</fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>555-222</fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-row bgcolor="#A7BFDE">
    <fo:table-cell>Cecil</fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>Crawford</fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>555-333</fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
</fo:root>
```

Note the alternating background color for each `table-row`.

Comment: The attribute for background color is background-color not bgcolor.

Comment: yes, good point man ...<fo:table-row  background-color="{$bgclr}" >

Comment: @michael.hor257k Shouldn't the `test="position() mod 2"` be a boolean expression like `test="position() mod 2 = 1"`

Comment: @DavidArtmann The content of the `test` attribute **is** a boolean expression. And `boolean(0)` returns `false()`, while any other number returns `true()`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thx, my bad. :) PS: got on this, because the IntelliJ XSL(T) wrapper suggested me to do so.