# XSLT How can I wrap each 3 elements by div?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML document with `<item>` elements, and i'd want to wrap each 3 of them in `<div>` If there is less than 3 elements, wrap them too.

```
<shop>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  .....
  <item></item>
</shop>
```

So result must be something like this

```
<div class="line">
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
</div>
....
<div class="line">
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table with alternating row colors via XSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469917/html-table-with-alternating-row-colors-via-xsl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A much simpler solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="item[position() mod 3 = 1]">
  <div>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    ".|following-sibling::*[not(position() > 2)]"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<shop>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>      
    <item></item>
</shop>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div>
   <item/>
   <item/>
   <item/>
</div>
<div>
   <item/>
   <item/>
   <item/>
</div>
<div>
   <item/>
</div>
```

**Update**:

The OP has clarified that he needs a transformation that would process the XML document on **this page**. Everything should be copied as-is with the exception of any group of `<item>` elements that must be grouped by three and each group wrapped into a `<div>`.

Here is the code for this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()[self::item and position() mod 3 = 1]">
   <div>
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    ".|following-sibling::*[not(position()>2)]"/>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "node()[self::item and not(position() mod 3 = 1)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you help me to do the same thing with this document http://thermex.tmweb.ru/xml/xml_document.xml ?

Comment: Sure, but you need to explain a little bit more. Maybe ask a new question? (nad don't forget to accept an answer for this one :) )

Comment: @Ruslan-Savenok: Sure, but I cannot know what is to be grouped in the new XML document

Comment: I think that there is no need to ask new question because task is the same but xml document a little bit different. Please check the example i've attached, i need to select only `<item>` tags

Comment: @Dimitre `thermex.tmweb.ru/xml/xml_document.xml`

Comment: @Ruslan-Savenok: There are only 3 `<item>` elements there -- it is meaningless to group these.

Comment: CMS generates that xml and returns all of items in current category

Comment: @Ruslan-Savenok: so, you want everything as- is with the only exception of the `<item>` elements being grouped by 3, do you?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my English, I'm from Ukraine :)

Comment: @Ruslan-Savenok: I updated my answer with the solution to your new problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your solution will be very similar to this:

[HTML table with alternating row colors via XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469917/html-table-with-alternating-row-colors-via-xsl)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate, just very similar.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I think that partitioning a sequence wraping groups whether with `table`, `div` or `your-mother-told-me-so` elements is just the same, thus making the question an alternative rephrase. But unless there is a thoughtful binding reason, just a link doesn't make this a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <xsl:for-each select"item">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count(item) mod 3 = 0">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:foreach>
```

I haven't tried this, but important is the test in the foreach loop. `count(item) mod 3 = 0` than you can react every third time.

Comment: It would take about as long to try it as it did to type "I haven't tried this."

Comment: And when you tried, you would see that this code doesn't produce any output at all.

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!--  the number of items to include in each group -->
    <xsl:variable name="group" select="3" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="shop/item[position() mod $group = 1]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item" mode="inner">
        <!-- handle items appropriately here -->
        <item/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <div class="line">
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select=".|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $group]"
                mode="inner" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input:

```
<shop>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
  <item></item>
</shop>
```

Produces:

```
<div class="line">
    <item />
    <item />
    <item />
</div>
<div class="line">
    <item />
    <item />
    <item />
</div>
<div class="line">
    <item />
    <item />
    <item />
</div>
<div class="line">
    <item />
    <item />
    <item />
</div>
<div class="line">
    <item />
    <item />
</div>
```